# Why can't I update my manifest.json file?

Tags: shiny, manifest.json

I try to update the manifest file of my shiny app to include a new package.

```
> rsconnect::writeManifest()
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Warning messages:
1: In file.append(to[okay], from[okay]) : write error during file append
2: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file '/tmp/Rtmpe1Ghqi/file55c4157bd1a/data/test/DATA/dom.rds', reason 'No space left on device'
3: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file '/tmp/Rtmpe1Ghqi/file55c4157bd1a/data/test/DATA/rt.rds', reason 'No space left on device'
4: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file '/tmp/Rtmpe1Ghqi/file55c4157bd1a/data/test/DATA/list_rt.rds', reason 'No space left on device'
```

I could create the manifest until last week without any problem.

What could be the reason for this error?

Thank you,

Comment: `use warnings() to see the first 50`

Comment: yes, sorry, I have edited my previous message